# Class Names in Xamarin to Objective C binding

Tags: xamarin.ios

We are binding a library from Objective C to C#. We want to use different names in our classes in C#.

Do the class in C# and the objective C class must have the same name?

I know that using the MonoTouch.Foundation.ExportAttribute in the methods in C# we can specify different names for the methods and properties... however, I haven't found how to do the same for classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can specify your own type name byt specifying a `Name` property to the `[BaseType]` attribute. E.g.

```
 [BaseType (typeof (NSObject), Name="NSURL")]
 public interface NSUrl {
 }
```

That, real life, example allows you to use `NSUrl` in C# instead of the Objective-C `NSURL` type name. You can see many more examples, like the one above, in [github](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/foundation.cs#L2499).